# Linux SSH through multiple jumpboxes

Tags: linux, ssh, remote-desktop

I am trying to perform the following tasks:

I am on a Linux VM, on my Windows laptop (corporate)
I want to do:

ssh to jump / bastion host (linux) (this is technically optional) --> jump through rdp host
(windows) --> jump to target host (linux)

I typically log onto bastion host (linux) and have a screen there that I do my work on, but I'm not opposed to making an alias just for this task.

Currently from my Linux VM, I have commands to jump to target linux servers for specific tasks that I need segregated on separate tasks.

I've already reviewed the following URL's and the commands just aren't working for me. Am I missing something?

[RDP from Linux through ssh tunnel chain](https://superuser.com/questions/1006901/rdp-from-linux-through-ssh-tunnel-chain)

[RDP over SSH Tunnel through intermediate Linux server](https://superuser.com/questions/1144748/rdp-over-ssh-tunnel-through-intermediate-linux-server)

nutshell:
bypass windows when using windows as a jump to linux

start on linux, jump through windows, end on a different linux

in a perfect world:  linux1 --> linux2 --> windows1 --> linux 3. But I will take Linux2 --> Win1 --> Linux3

from 1 command w/ SSH keys

Comment: Linux target via RDP jumphost? That sounds like you're trying to do the complete opposite of what these URLs are talking about?

Comment: Correct, I want to:
start on linux, jump through windows, end on a different linux

Comment: What's the official purpose of the RDP jumpbox, though? Just authentication, or something like screen recording, or a regular workstation?

Comment: Because someone is too lazy to map an entire new system to the main network and want to map just the jumpbox on an isolated network.